# is this excel to mysql conversion possible

Tags: mysql, sql, database, excel

So i want to convert an excel database that manage size/color/stock of products but i think it might not be possible.

the excel look like :
[image]

[image]
(etc..)

size are in yellow, color in red and the stock is based on the size

For example the stock of color "Blanc" in L will be 3  and "marine" in M will be 2

My database already have all the products and i have a table "gestion_stock" with foreign key product/size/color and stock :

[image]

the keys refer to table like :

[image]

so i was wondering if there is a way to convert excel in my sql database,

I guess it's impossible since the Size/Color/Stock management are totally different, so i guess i will have to manually add all this in my db..
if someone can leads me to a better solution it would be very cool !
thanks

Answer (score 0):

> so i was wondering if there is a way to convert excel in my sql
>   database

Yes there is.

Save your excel data (mean the file) to a `*.csv` format

Use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to load the data from csv to your MySQL table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\';
```

Finally, do a `SELECT` from your newly imported table and verufy the data

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

You should also consider checking [Chapter 7 Export Excel Data into MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html)

Comment: Yes but it will have the same pattern that the excel file and i will not have the foreign key on the size/color.
i will have to manually add all the keys :/